# Servicestack: restrict MVC action by role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, servicestack

I want to restrict an ASP.NET MVC action for a role. I think it should be something like this:

```
[Restrict(RestrictPermission = new []{Permissions.Admin, Permissions.Admin_Export  })]
public class LocalAdmin { }
```

How to remove access to action for some role?

Comment: What issues have you had with what you have tried so far?

Comment: @bruffalobill i didn't tried anything, because i don't know how. Service stack documentation doesn't contain appropriate info. Code above - is just pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [[Restrict] Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) is only for restricting access to Service based on Request Attributes of how the Service was called.

See the [Required Role and Permission attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#requiredrole-and-requiredpermission-attributes) for examples on restricting access to Services based on whether the User has the Required Role in order to access The Service.

The [mvc.servicestack.net](http://mvc.servicestack.net/) Live Demo shows an Example of [Restricting Access by Role](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc/Controllers/RequiresRoleController.cs) which you can apply on your MVC Controllers that inherit `ServiceStackController`, e.g:

```
[RequiredRole("TheRole")]
public class RequiresRoleController : ServiceStackController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var session = SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        return View(session);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i have now.